# How to read text between multi-level parenthetical expressions

Tags: java, string, parsing, substring

I am trying to parse through text to see if it is a valid expression. I am faced with the following problem.

((5*4) + 3) is a valid expression.

How would I parse this to allow me to analyze what is in one level of parentheses at a time.
For example, I would want to have the following expressions returned in seperate substrings so that one substring reads "5*4" and another **seperate** substring reads "(5*4) + 3"

I know I can use substring as follows:

```
String test = "test (542)";

test = test.substring(test.indexOf("(") + 1);
test = test.substring(0, test.indexOf(")"));
```

But how can I best approach handling multiple levels of parentheses of an unknown string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Divide and Conquer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) would be a promising approach. You could define a **recursive** function, which will only need to handle a simple base case (like 5*4) explicitly. Whenever there are parentheses, call the function again with the text inside the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, I found that by trimming the surrounding parentheses it would be much easier to handle! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). If you only validate an expression, you do not need to implement all the algorithm. Your expression is valid when you have all the required operators and operands. In YouTube, you can see [Shunting Yard Algorithm - Intro and Reverse Polish Notation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzVVjboyb0s).